# Stripe gateway and codeigniter error

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, stripe-payments

I have integrated Stripe with codeigniter by adding the php library of Stripe in the libraries folder and calling it from a controller like this:

```
public function index()
{
    require_once(APPPATH.'libraries/stripe/init.php');

    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_3LrFVGsJkjh65g8kj34dszEM2");

    \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
     "amount"        => 30000, // amount in cents, again
     "currency"      => "usd",
     "customer"      => "cus_8lVKwCV52ShUc7",
     "description"   => "Monthly Fee",
     "metadata"      => array(
        "Period"            => "May - June 2016"
         )
      )
    );
}
```

And im getting [a curl error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIotF.png)

I am not really sure if doing the integration on the correct way or do i need to add something else to my code. Thank you!

Comment: Considering curl_init is a [cURL module function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php), chances are you don't have PHP cURL installed.

Comment: The curious thing is that first i try it without codeigniter on my local machine and it works, then i try to add it to codeigniter and im getting this error.

Comment: this is just a guess but try it without the namespaces. you are calling it from a codeigniter library so maybe you don't need them?

Comment: I'm getting **Class 'Stripe' not found**

Comment: yeah you might need to add some code to make it work as a ci library. suggest that you check out github for examples  i just did a quick search https://github.com/miharbi/codeIgniter-stripe-library i'm sure there are more on there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883159/codeigniter-how-to-load-stripe-php-library-in-project#answer-23885108).

The right way to load a library in CodeIgniter is to use the loader method:

```
$this->load->library('stripe');
```

Then you can use any of the methods specific to the loaded library, like this:

```
$this->stripe->setApiKey("sk_test_3LrFVGsJkjh65g8kj34dszEM2");
```

If that doesn't do it, here's another useful link: https://github.com/chrismackie28/php-stripe

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped me. Just to point out one typo  **this->load->library('stripe');**

Comment: if it helped you solve the problem, please accept the answer and/or up vote it. Thanks